# .reduce method for arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi here is some code off w3 schools using the array reduce method. I am trying to learn how to use this, however I am a bit confused on why this code even works. The reason why is that `numbers.reduce(getSum)` doesent take parameters in the function getSum. How does our code even know how many things are inside  of the array and how to sum them if we dont even give parameters to the getSum function. On w3schools it says `array.reduce(function(total,currentValue,currentIndex,arr),initialValue)`, and also says that total and currentValue are required. But we don't even have them here do we? we just have our function! Help please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>

<script>
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Heres another example.. not sure what the difference is

```
var numbers = [15.5, 2.3, 1.1, 4.7];

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + Math.round(num);
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum,0);
}
```

Comment: Difference is in initial value: `undefined` vs `0`. with `undefined` first array element will be used at initial. Also, second has round all numbers to integers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce might explain it a bit better but basically it can be written as `numbers.reduce(function (total, num) { return total + num; });` if `getSum` were replaced by an anonymous function. The rest can be better explained by the link.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of reduce function is `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`.

This means that getSum is called as a **callback**.

What's a callback? To put it easy, it is a reference to a function that will be called in a second moment.

An easy example (but the web is full of guides on callback):

```
function print(value) {
  console.log(value)
}

function callCallback(callback) {
  callback('Hello world!');
}

callCallback(print);
```

As you can see *print* is a function, and a reference to it is passed as argument to `callCallback()`. The function is then called inside `callCallback()`.

Let's go back to your question:

`reduce()` requires a reference to a function as first argument.

reduce is a function, and inside it will do some things (to see a possible implementation, [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill)).

Somewhere `reduce()` will call back the function you passed as argument, passing right params.

We have reduce that is something like this:

```
reduce(callback) {
  callback(previousValue, currentValue);
}
```

So for each value in the array the function you passed as argument will be called, and its arguments will be populated with `previousValue` and `currentValue`

Of course reduce() is definitely longer, but at the end it takes thing from the array, do some magic, and pass to the function you passed as callback argument.

Comment: Im kind of confused. How does our program know how to get the first , second and third value of our array? the getsum function can add them, but how do we get them?

Comment: So basically reduce() has a built in way of going through each element of the array?

Comment: @cresjoy yap, since it is a function added to the prototype of `Array`, it uses `this` keyword to access the values of the array itself. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it said that in w3schools

Answer (score 1):

In the function `getSum`, you have two parameters, `total` and `num` Those are equivalent to `total` and `currentValue`, respectively, in your w3 schools example. In javascript, your function doesn't have to have the same variable names in the function. Two arguments are required to the function you pass to `reduce`, and the first will be used as a "running total" and the second as the "current value".

As far as the question, how does it know how many values are inside the array, take a look at the polyfill provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill). It gives some insight as to how one might implement a `reduce` function for an array, and to know how long an array is.

Comment: "Two arguments are required to the function you pass to reduce", this is what I really needed, now I just need to understand how it knows what values are in the array.

Comment: @cresjoy Okay, so it's implemented as a function in the Array prototype. The basic idea is that the function will call the callback function for _every_ value in the array. In essence, it does `var value; for {var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { value = callback(this[i]); } return value; `

Comment: oh. so thats built into reduce itself?

Comment: @cresjoy yes, it is. `reduce` basically means, combine every value in this array using the passed function and give me back a single value.

Answer (score 1):

array.reduce(callback[,initialValue]).

Callback = a function that executes on each value of the array, having 4 arguments.

1) previousValue = value returned in the previous callback OR the inital value given with reduce.

2) currentValue = value off the current element in the array.

3) currentIndex = index of the current element in the array.

4) array = the array that it is called on

initialValue is optional, and gives our previous value a start value in the first callback.

SO actually you have the arguments. the initial value( being the result of the previous callback), the actual number, the index of the number, and your numbers array.

EDIT : If you don't give an initial value, your previous value will be the first element of the array and your current value the second one.

EDIT 2 : Your previous value in your first run will be 65, and your current value will be 44. They add up, give a result which is 109, and give that as result value. The function is called until you completed your array. So that means that the return value of you first callback ( 109 ) will be the previousValue of your second callback. Again it will add up the previous ( 109 ) and the current, being the next ( 3rd ) element in your array. They add them up ( 109 + 12 ) and return the value for the next callback, etc.. until you've gone trough whole the array. At the end it just returns you the total.

Comment: Since we can have 4 parameters and (getsum) provides 2, if we do (getsum,0) is that just the current index? I.E whats the difference between doing (getsum) vs (getsum,0)

Comment: @cresjoy no, by doing (getsum,0), you're giving the reduce function it's second parameter which is the intial value.Remember, the function is like this array.reduce(callback, initValue). init value is optional.callback is your actual getsum function, in that function, you MUST have a current value.

Comment: @cresjoy I edited my answer, look at EDIT 2, you should get the idea of how the function works.

Comment: Oh. Can i think of the (getsum,5) for example as pushing 5 to the array, and then running the getsum function all over again?

Comment: @cresjoy doing that, instead if beginning with 65 as previous value and 44 as currentvalue, you will start with 5 as previous value, and 65 as currentValue, the first result will be 5 + 65 instead of 65 + 44

Comment: Great makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @cresjoy no problem, hope you get the essentials of it. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

you have to differentiate between a function invocation and a function definition.

function definition

```
function test() {}
```

function invocation

```
test();
```

passing a function requires a function definition not an invocation, hence you can pass the reference (variable defining the function) or the function definition itself.

```
numbers.reduce(functionVariableReference); // pass function definition
numbers.reduce(function() {}) //anonymous function definition
```

the Array.reduce needs a callback to execute on each element, this callback is passed the following parameters on invocation, `total,currentValue,currentIndex,arr`

Another Example:

```
function test(nOne, nTwo) {console.log(nOne + nTwo);}
function passTwoAndThree(callback) {callback(2,3)};
passTwoAndThree(test) // will log 5;
```